# Why are the minimize and maximize buttons "crooked"?

Tags: window, taskbar

Sorry if the title isn't vere descriptive, but I don't know how to describe this:

[image]

It happens only when the windows are maximized.

Comment: This looks like a graphic bug. You could try to change the theme and see if it persist or is it specific to the default Unity theme. Also, provide some info about your graphic card and drivers so people can help.

Comment: I already use a different theme and the taskbar doesn't even appear. This picture is from the Unity dash.

Comment: My graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6310. I am not using proprietarian drivers because the installation always fails.